# NSXMLParser Error

Tags: nsxmlparser

I am fetching data from this url "http://potlocator.com/locationXML.php",

But while parsing the data with NSXMLParser, i am getting this error,

found Error Operation could not be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 68.)

What might be the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was an error in parsing.  Check out the [class reference page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you own the document or have any control over it, but it is not a clean document. I haven't tried parsing it with NSXMLParser though so I'm not sure it stumbles over the error.

The file contains a tag "" which is closed with "" (note the extra space after "id")

This might definitely cause the parser to abort operation.

Also, but that could just be me, the file loads pretty slow. So the parser might just think its too slow and quit? I dunno.

Anyway, I'd look into the extra space in  first

Answer (score 0):

you can get full version error info on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSXMLParser. I think this could help you.

PS: NSXMLParserNAMERequiredError = 68,